# pyinstaller not reading my hook file and doesn't work with win32com.shell

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pywin32

According to the docs of pyinstaller, if you name a file `hook-fully.qualified.import.name.py` it will read this file whenever you do an import of the matching `.py` file.

However, my script looks like this:

```
import pythoncom
from win32com.shell import shell
from win32com import storagecon
...
```

And pyinstaller refuses to recognize `win32com.shell` with the following error: `ImportError: No module named 'win32com.shell'`.
So I've created `hook-win32com.shell.py` with the following code:

```
hiddenimports = [
    'win32com.shell.shell',
]
```

pyinstaller never reads this file, however it does read `hook-win32com.py` so I've also tried with just adding `'win32com.shell' to the above hook file but that didn't do much.

1. How do I get pyinstaller to read my hook file
2. How do I get it to include `win32com.shell`? (So i get rid of "No module named" in runtime of the .exe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the case with: https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/1322

Apparently the new python3 graph is now used everywhere in pyinstaller, so this bug seems to apply for python2 users as well.

I suggest rewriting win32com.shell calls with ctypes.shell32, or cffi.

Comment: I wrote the question/issue on github, but you'll get the sweet score for mentnioning it : )

Comment: Indeed you did, (now that I've checked!) - and it was useful when I had the exact same issue! In my case, I was only using two functions in shell, so it was easy for me to rewrite those calls.  Thanks.